# I dont understand this http get

Tags: java, http, get

I want to get data from https://my.playstation.com/logged-in/my-profile/.

I analyzed the site with Firebug and I got these results:

[image: Firebug screenshot]

As you can see there is a `GET /playstation/psn/profile/psnloginbar?0.27654...`

I tried to do:

```
String url = "/playstation/psn/profile/psnloginbar?0.3596450921613723&_=1432238143275";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Explain _But it is not working_.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to pass the entire URL. How else would it know that the domain is my.playstation.com?

Comment: Your URL `String` isn't valid, it should have (at least) `https://my.playstation.com/` prefixed to it, or some such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modified code below is an example of a successful connection. 
Note the full URL. 
I think your next issue is that you'll have to figure out a way to authenticate yourself because your original URL (/playstation/psn/profile/psnloginbar?0.27654...) sits behind a form login screen.

```
String url = "https://www.playstation.com/en-us/";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
     //This is the http response code :  
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    // To actually get the html body text, read the stream, 
    // below is just one of many ways to to this:

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(obj.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine); //<-- prints each line of html                  
    in.close();
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot, ill try to login someway, but after that, how could i retrieve the information that im looking for? because it doesnt appear in the html as plain text, may be with jquery?

pd: im new with this.

Comment: con.getResponseCode(); will only give you the http response code. 200 = OK , 301 means Redirect ...etc. You need to actually read the InputStream in order to get the html contents of the body. Will amend answer.